# Hudson Downstream Projects Failure Notification

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have 2 projects. One of them contains integration tests (lets call it `Project B`) and the other is the main project (`Project A`). I configured hudson so when `Project A` is build,  `Project B` will then be built. My Problem is that if `Project A` is successful and `Project B` fails, the person who broke the build does not get notified.

There is the option `Send separate emails to individuals who broke the build` for both projects activated, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Blame Upstream Committers Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin). Have a look at it. The description sounds like the perfect answer to your question.

Alternatively you can try to use the [Clone Workspace SCM Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin), but I think the other one is the better fit.

Answer (score 0):

How do you identify who broke the build if a test fails ?  You can't use the check-in ID like you can for build A, so it seems to me you'd be better off just emailing a fixed list of people if project B fails.

Alternatively, you could just combine projects A and B; then whoever checked in the changes flagged in project A will be emailed when the tests fail.